# Incrementally build vector of variable pointers at compile time

Tags: c++, c++14

I am trying to solve a problem where I have a number of scattered variable declarations (in a single compilation unit), and I want to build a vector of their addresses at compile time (if not possible as a space efficient vector, other data structures would work as well, such as a linked list).

```
static type var1;
static type var2;
static type var3;

// ...
for (type *i : varlist)
   do something with each varX
```

As an expanded example and rationale, assume I have a scripting language, and I have a way to modify script variables from C++ by getting a handle, say `scriptvar *`. These handles can be found by calling a `get_var` function with a name:

```
scriptvar *var1 = get_var ("namespace::var1");
scriptvar *var2 = get_var ("namespace::var2");
```

This is slow, so I wish to cache the `scriptvar *` values in global variables. Unfortunately, I must only call `get_var` after initialising the script language, which might happen late in the program, so I cannot just use `get_var` in an initializer expression, but have to delay calling it.

It would be nice if I could write a `scriptvarwrapper` class or use some other means that would allow me to declare these global handle variables at any point, but also built a space-efficient vector of these vairables at compile time that I can access later:

```
struct scriptvarwrapper
{
  scriptvar *handle;
  const char *name;
  / ...
};

static scriptvarwrapper var1 ("namespace::var1");
static scriptvarwrapper var2 ("namespace::var2");
static scriptvarwrapper var3 ("namespace::var3");

void init_vars ()
{
  for (scriptvarwrapper *i : somecontainer)
     i->handle = get_var (i->name);
}
```

It would be ideal if this container would end up being just an array/vector-like data structure in memory that consists of the pointers to these variables. Obviously, the goal is to build this at compile time, so solutions putting something into a `std::vector` in the constructor would not solve the problem.

**Update:**

To clarify the problem - what I want is a solution that automatically compiles an array or list of all these declared variables at compile time, without me having to list them individually and without a constructor building a list dynamically at runtime, presumably through some cool and nifty metaprogramming method, such as a constexpr function that somehow chains all these vairables together in a list or, preferably, something that results in just an array of pointers to all scriptvarwrapper objects in memory, either terminated with a special value or with known size.

Specifically, having to put the scriptvarwrapper objects into a static array manually will not do, nor will putting them into a std::vector in their constructor suffice.

The rationale for this is maintainability - if I add a variable anywhere in my program, I do not want to have to list it separately again because that is easy to forget - and efficiency - I do not want to build a dynamic data structure at runtime for what is, effectively, a constant known at compiletime.

The preference for some kind of array is due to efficiency - a solution that results in a 100 byte structure for each such object at compiletime is of course not very useful, likewise would be allocating a very large array just for future expansion.

**Update 2:**

To clarify further, the exact syntax and layout and type of the storage is not that important. What is important is that I can have a number of independent and scattered-through-the-file(s) variable declarations and their addresses are automatically and without manual enumeration put into some kind of read-only container that can somehow be iterated over at runtime to find all these declarations.

The goal is to efficiently find all those variables without the possibility of me forgetting to list one separately, nor to have to build data structures dynamically at runtime, since the information is all known at compile time, and C++ is such a cool language with compile time metaprogramming. Alas, I don't know how or if it even is possible.

**Update 3:**

Sorry for all these updates, I am learning how difficult it is to express this problem. Here is an example of how things could look like:

```
static scriptvarwrapper var1 ("name");
ADD_LIST (var1); // magic macro

static scriptvarwrapper var2 ("name");
ADD_LIST (var2);
```

The key here is that, although I have to list each variable and even use an ugly macro maybe, it is hard to overlook or forget to list a variable because the `ADD_LIST` is directly at the place of the declaration - remember, the declarations might be scattered all over a long file, or even in some include files, so I am looking for a solution that makes it hard to forget to include a declaration in my list.

Ideally, therefore, the constructor or the mere act of declaring a `scriptvarwrapper` would make sure its listed, so it can't be overlooked. A solution that puts everything in a `std::vector` in the constructor would work, except would feel ugly due to the runtime overhead.

As an old C hand that I am, I considered using GCC extensions to put these into their own ELF section, much like constructors themselves work on ELF systems - they are gathered by pointer into their own section, and all such sections are concatenated at link time, with a special object file at the end that delivers the sentinel end value.

Comment: can you cache variables using get_var right after initializing script language?

Comment: maybe an `std::map` could do the trick

Comment: @AndrewKashpur if you mean whether the handle returned by get_var stays valid indefinitely, the answer is yes for this example. The problem is that get_var cannot be called at program initialisation, otherwise the consstructor could simply call it.

Comment: @user2176127 a std::map can't be used at compile time, can it?

Comment: Your problem could be solved by 'reflection' but stupid C++ does not currently offer this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completly sure if I understand you question, but why not simply use classic old arrays:

```
static int var1;
static int var2;
static int var3;

static int* vars[] = { &var1, &var2, &var3, nullptr };

for(size_t i = 0; vars[i]; ++i)
    std::cout << *vars[i] << std::endl;
```

This should work for all data types and it is guaranteed to happen at compile time.

The following version is also built at compile time (at least in Visual C++ 2017):

```
static const auto vararr = std::array<int*, 3>{ &var1, &var2, &var3 };
```

The same can be done for you scriptvarwrapper:

```
struct scriptvarwrapper
{
    scriptvar *handle;
    const char *name;
};

static scriptvarwrapper vars[] = {
    {nullptr, "var1"},
    {nullptr, "var2"},
    {nullptr, nullptr}
};

void init_vars()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; vars[i].name; ++i)
        vars[i].handle = get_var(vars[i].name);
}
```

In C++ the script variable 'var1' can be accessed by vars[0].handle and 'var2' is in vars[1].handle.

Maybe you'd prefer the following solution:

```
struct scriptvarwrapper
{
    scriptvar **handle;
    const char *name;
};

static scriptvar *var1 = nullptr;
static scriptvar *var2 = nullptr;

static scriptvarwrapper vars[] = {
    { &var1, "var1"},
    { &var2, "var2"},
    {nullptr, nullptr}
};

void init_vars()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; vars[i].name; ++i)
        *vars[i].handle = get_var(vars[i].name);
}
```

var1 and var2 as scriptvars, initialized to nullptr and added to a compile time array 'vars' using the 'scriptvarwrapper'. In 'init_vars' the scriptvars are initialized and can then be used by accessing 'var1' and 'var2' (without even knowing of the compile time array used for initializing them)

A non-compile-time but simple-to-use solution:

```
class ScriptVar
{
public:
    ScriptVar(const char *name_)
        : name(name_)
    {
        vars.insert(this);
    }

    scriptvar* operator->()
    {
        return handle;
    }

    static void initVars()
    {
        for (auto var : vars)
            var->handle = get_var(var->name);
    }

private:
    static std::set<ScriptVar*> vars;
    const char *name;
    scriptvar *handle;
};

const ScriptVar var1("namespace::var1");
const ScriptVar var2("namespace::var2");
```

Each defined ScriptVar is registered in ScriptVar::vars and after calling ScriptVar::initVars() all defined ScriptVars can be accessed with the -> operator.

Comment: These are nice alternatives, but none of them compute the list at compile time - the first few require me to do the job manually, the last is at runtime. I will try to improve m,y question in the hope that it becomes clearer.

Comment: I think what you really need is some kind of preprocessor which offers some reflection functionality. I'm afraid this can't be done with standard c++ at least until C++20 (see https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/reflections-on-the-reflection-proposals.html)